# verify-email route does not pass "auth" middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

The email verification process not working.
I send email correctly. When I click on link to verify the email, I have been redirected to login page.

It seems the route does not pass `auth` middleware.
This is how I defined the route:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController::class, 'verify'])
        ->name('verification.verify');
});
```

This is the function in the controller (it's the standard laravel function, I did not edited it):

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user()->getKey())) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($request->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    if ($response = $this->verified($request)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

The `auth` middleware is the default middleware come with laravel.

Comment: *"I have been redirected to login page"* that means you're supposed to be logged in in order to access that page (route named `verification.verify`).

Comment: read the official laravel documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification

Comment: Hi @GiacomoM, as has been mentioned the auth middleware will check if a user is logged in and if not ask them to login.  Your 2 options are to not require the user to be logged in by removing the auth middleware, or the better way is to just login, Laravel will then direct them to the verify route as it remembers the route that was tried to be accessed prior to the login request.

Comment: @ColinMD why you think its better to just login and after verify email? There is no reason to do login to verify email.

Comment: Its about preference the flow of the App, generally user signs up and will automatically be signed in but as not verified will get the not verified screen, they receive email, hit the link, they are signed in so it grants access straight into the app.  If the user is not required to sign in, they press the email link, which verifies email, Laravel will try to redirect them to an auth required page, realises they aren't signed in, so will take them to a login screen anyway.

Comment: So in both scenarios you will get a login screen but I prefer for users to be signed in and quite often they are already signed in as they have just created the account.

Comment: I also have a feeling that Laravel does a check to ensure that the logged in user is the same as the one passed in the string.  Even in your own implementation you are presuming there is a logged in user every time you call $request->user() , so even if it passed auth you are going to hit issues if they aren't logged in.